# How to make find command in dos fail if it finds a string in a test file?

Tags: batch-file, find, dos

I have to search a text file for the string "Failed" and want the 'find' command should fail or return fail  if it finds the string.

Comment: Please [edit] with more detail to clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
findstr /c:"Failed" filename.txt && Echo Failed found || Echo Failed not found
```

or

```
findstr /c:"Failed" filename.txt 
If Errorlevel 1 echo Failed not found or file couldn't be read
```

See `findstr /?` and `if /?`.

Findstr 0 = found, 1 = not found, and 2 = file couldn't be read.